# Which email validation RegEx is used by Struts?

Tags: java, regex

According to Struts2 documentation (https://struts.apache.org/docs/email-validator.html), the following is the RegEx used for email validation:

```
\\b^['_a-z0-9-\\+](\\.['_a-z0-9-\\+])@[a-z0-9-](\\.[a-z0-9-])\\.([a-z]{2}|aero|arpa|asia|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|nato|net|org|pro|tel|travel|xxx)$\\b
```

However, this regex seems to only match strings of the form *x.y@z.w.com* (i.e. a word character followed by a dot and then another word character, on both sides of the `@` sign). I've confirmed it using the

```
testString.matches(regex)
```

method, where *regex* is the one above.

Can someone confirm if this form is indeed what the regex matches or point me to the correct regex that Struts uses?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/develop/xwork-core/src/main/java/com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/validators/EmailValidator.java#L83.

Answer (score -2):

Can you try `^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$` ?

Comment: The question wasn't "what is a good email validation regex?", it was "what is the correct regex that struts uses?".